# jQuery UI Draggable - drag beyond absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I am unable to see the elements that i am dragging once they leave a parent element that has absolute positioning. (Cant see the draggable helper as it moves)

Check out the example at http://nairobi.io/tests/jquery-ui-draggable
Kindly help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misspelled "appendTo" as "apendTo" in your draggable initialiser (line 138), which means the helper is not being added to the right place.

Comment: or remove overflow in ul.add-segment

Comment: OMG... I am shocked by how quick you guys fixed the problem! I had tried so many things in so many days including adding the .disableSelection() at the end which im not even sure what it does. So thankful!

Comment: Oh btw.. @RaúlMartín as you can see the overflow is crucial in that design. How else could i make that sidebar scrollable?